# Importing XML file into MYSQL table and parsing element labels into column headers and values

Tags: mysql, xml

I am trying to import xml files into sql tables and need to parse the element name is the column and value is the rows

example:

```
<identification-elements>
            <element name="wmo_synop_id" uom="unitless" value="71203"/>
            <element name="stn_nam" uom="unitless" value="Kelowna"/>
            <element code-src="std_code_src" code-type="station_type" name="stn_typ" uom="code" value="12"/>
            <element name="date_tm" uom="datetime" value="2018-07-11T19:00:00.000Z"/>
            <element name="lat" uom="°" value="49.95722"/>
            <element name="long" uom="°" value="-119.37778"/>
            <element name="stn_elev" uom="m" value="429.4"/>
            <element name="icao_stn_id" uom="unitless" value="CYLW"/>
            <element code-src="std_code_src" code-type="report_type" name="rpt_typ" uom="code" value="0"/>
            <element name="data_pvdr" uom="unitless" value="NAV CANADA"/>
            <element name="data_attrib_not" uom="unitless" value="Observational data provided by NAV CANADA. All rights reserved."/>
            <element name="clim_id" uom="unitless" value="1123939"/>
            <element name="msc_id" uom="unitless" value="1123939"/>
            </identification-elements>
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score -1):

Quick and dirty.

Open a text editor, paste the XML in - save as text file.

Remove all leading/trailing tags.

Find and replace: '<element name='  with nothing

Find and replace: ' uom='    with ',' (comma)

Find and replace: ' value="'  with ',' (comma)

Find and replace: '"/>' with nothing

### Save

This way you'll get CSV (comma separated values)

from:

```
<element name="wmo_synop_id" uom="unitless" value="71203"/>
```

to:

```
"wmo_synop_id","unitless",71203
```

Save the file.

In MySQL create table that has 3 fields
Varchar, Varchar, Int

Then use the mysql: LOAD DATA INFILE Syntax

to load the file into the table.

Comment: Thanks, Felix, but there is more to the xml than posted and I need to do it programmatically. There are thousands of them. This is just to extract the metadata then there is a data stream that comes after it. Same syntax "name","uom","value" I was hoping to use 'Load XML' but I may have to parse it into a csv then load it.